# Exception in thread main while parsing MappingNode

Tags: java, mysql, grails, yaml

I do not know at all what this error code is, does anyone have an insight to this? I am very new to grails and as such the error codes below are unknown to me. can't make out heads or tails of it. 
- Grails Beginner here
Running Grails 3.1.2
MySQL Workbench 6

```
grails> run-app
| Running application...
Exception in thread "main" while parsing MappingNode
 in 'reader', line 31, column 13:
                dbCreate: update
                ^
Duplicate key: properties
 in 'reader', line 47, column 1:
    ---
    ^

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlProcessor$StrictMapAppenderConstructor.constructMapping(YamlProcessor.java:407)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.SafeConstructor$ConstructYamlMap.construct(SafeConstructor.java:489)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructObject(BaseConstructor.java:182)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructMapping2ndStep(BaseConstructor.java:373)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.SafeConstructor.constructMapping2ndStep(SafeConstructor.java:147)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructMapping(BaseConstructor.java:354)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlProcessor$StrictMapAppenderConstructor.constructMapping(YamlProcessor.java:403)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.SafeConstructor$ConstructYamlMap.construct(SafeConstructor.java:489)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructObject(BaseConstructor.java:182)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructMapping2ndStep(BaseConstructor.java:373)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.SafeConstructor.constructMapping2ndStep(SafeConstructor.java:147)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructMapping(BaseConstructor.java:354)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlProcessor$StrictMapAppenderConstructor.constructMapping(YamlProcessor.java:403)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.SafeConstructor$ConstructYamlMap.construct(SafeConstructor.java:489)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructObject(BaseConstructor.java:182)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructMapping2ndStep(BaseConstructor.java:373)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.SafeConstructor.constructMapping2ndStep(SafeConstructor.java:147)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructMapping(BaseConstructor.java:354)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlProcessor$StrictMapAppenderConstructor.constructMapping(YamlProcessor.java:403)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.SafeConstructor$ConstructYamlMap.construct(SafeConstructor.java:489)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructObject(BaseConstructor.java:182)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructDocument(BaseConstructor.java:141)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.getData(BaseConstructor.java:108)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml$1.next(Yaml.java:471)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlProcessor.process(YamlProcessor.java:158)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlProcessor.process(YamlProcessor.java:136)
        at org.grails.config.yaml.YamlPropertySourceLoader.load(YamlPropertySourceLoader.groovy:84)
        at org.grails.config.yaml.YamlPropertySourceLoader.load(YamlPropertySourceLoader.groovy:47)
        at org.springframework.boot.env.PropertySourcesLoader.load(PropertySourcesLoader.java:127)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.loadIntoGroup(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:462)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:449)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:374)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.addPropertySources(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:210)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:179)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:166)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:152)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:163)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:136)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:119)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.publishEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:111)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:65)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:330)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:55)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:365)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:354)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at grailsapp.Application.main(Application.groovy:8)
```

Comment: That's a problem with your *grails-app/conf/application.yml*. What's in that file?

Comment: Be careful with indentation in YML files.

Comment: Got it working. Not sure what was wrong with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YML file looks like this now. it works

```
---
grails:
    profile: web
    codegen:
        defaultPackage: grailsapp
info:
    app:
        name: '@info.app.name@'
        version: '@info.app.version@'
        grailsVersion: '@info.app.grailsVersion@'
spring:
    groovy:
        template:
            check-template-location: false

---
grails:
    mime:
        disable:
            accept:
                header:
                    userAgents:
                        - Gecko
                        - WebKit
                        - Presto
                        - Trident
        types:
            all: '*/*'
            atom: application/atom+xml
            css: text/css
            csv: text/csv
            form: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
            html:
              - text/html
              - application/xhtml+xml
            js: text/javascript
            json:
              - application/json
              - text/json
            multipartForm: multipart/form-data
            pdf: application/pdf
            rss: application/rss+xml
            text: text/plain
            hal:
              - application/hal+json
              - application/hal+xml
            xml:
              - text/xml
              - application/xml
    urlmapping:
        cache:
            maxsize: 1000
    controllers:
        defaultScope: singleton
    converters:
        encoding: UTF-8
    views:
        default:
            codec: html
        gsp:
            encoding: UTF-8
            htmlcodec: xml
            codecs:
                expression: html
                scriptlets: html
                taglib: none
                staticparts: none
---
hibernate:
    cache:
        queries: false
        use_second_level_cache: true
        use_query_cache: false
        region.factory_class: 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory'

endpoints:
    jmx:
        unique-names: true

dataSource:
    pooled: true
    jmxExport: true
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    username: root
    password: root

environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/inventory
    test:
        dataSource:
            driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
            username: sa
            password:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    production:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:h2:./prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
            properties:
                jmxEnabled: true
                initialSize: 5
                maxActive: 50
                minIdle: 5
                maxIdle: 25
                maxWait: 10000
                maxAge: 600000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
                validationQuery: SELECT 1
                validationQueryTimeout: 3
                validationInterval: 15000
                testOnBorrow: true
                testWhileIdle: true
                testOnReturn: false
                jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
                defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
```